# Install PHP 5.3 for one directory only

Tags: linux, centos, apache-http-server, php

I am on a CentOS 6 VPS, with Apache & PHP 5.4.

I need to have PHP 5.3 on only one folder, but no where else.

How do I install PHP 5.3 without conflicting with my current PHP installation and also make it available for that certain directory only?

Comment: Use mod_php 5.4.  Disable the mod_php engine for that folder and use the cgi php engine.

Comment: Sir, you have to be more specific, I'm very new to managing servers.